# Is it possible to solve the equation $\cos{x}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(xy)}}{y^2+1}dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

Can one solve for $x$ the integral equation
$$\cos{x}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(xy)}}{y^2+1}dy$$
The only thing I can think of is Taylor-expanding the cosine functions on both sides. If we do that, we find
integrability problems for the integral on the right near $\infty$.

Comment: In fact, the integral is very well-known and its value is $\frac{\pi e^{-|x|}}{2}$. So the equation becomes $\cos{x}=e^{-|x|}$ or i.e $\cos{x}e^{|x|}=1$. Clearly, $x=0$ is a solution, and if $x=x_0$ is a root so $x=-x_0$ is also a root. Then assume $x>0$. Now, i cant do anything.

Comment: Note that $$\cos x= \frac2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(xy)}}{y^2+1}dy= e^{-x}$$

Comment: @OnTheWay,  also $\cos x e^{x} = 1$ has a root on each segment of length $2\pi$ because of the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 6):

As said in comments and answers, you have to find the zeros of
$$f(x)=\cos(x)\,e^x-1$$ Discarding the trivial $x=0$, the roots will be close to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$.

Expanding as series
$$f(x)=-1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{k/2} e^{\pi  \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  k}{4}\right) \cos (\pi  (n+1))}{k!}\,\,\left(x-  (2 n+1)\frac \pi 2\right)^k$$

Truncating to some order and using series reversion
$$x_{(n)}= (2 n+1)\frac \pi 2 -(-1)^n e^{-(2 n+1)\frac \pi 2 }-e^{-(2 n+1)\pi}-(-1)^n \frac 53e^{-(2 n+1)\frac {3\pi} 2 }+\cdots$$

Using the above and, on purpose, a ridiculous number of decimal places
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & \color{red}{1.}30473068047848008109384008145 & 
                 1.29269571937339838116818912162 \\
 1 & \color{red}{4.7212927}8013366831230740888289 & 
                 4.72129275884768621662192954770 \\
 2 &  \color{red}{7.853593279971}32396845634670331 & 
                  7.85359327997124820007989934704 \\
 3 &  \color{red}{10.99559106306438158}32499112601 & 
                  10.9955910630643815829859174825 \\
 4 &  \color{red}{14.13716621620629242513549}21542 & 
                  14.1371662162062924251354912335 \\
 5 &  \color{red}{17.2787596260716731062494426607} & 
                  17.2787596260716731062494426607 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We could do better building the simple $[2,2]$ Padé approximant of $\cos(x)\, e^x$ around  $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$. Letting
$$x=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2-t$$ it just remains to solve the quadratic equation
$$\left(1+3 (-1)^n e^{\pi  \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right) t^2+3 \left(1-2 (-1)^n e^{\pi  \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right) t+6=0$$

Repeating the same calculations as above with the same ridiculous number of decimal places
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & \color{red}{1.2926}3854652920246811113073673 & 
                 1.29269571937339838116818912159 \\
 1 & \color{red}{4.72129275884}891607435040801353 & 
                 4.72129275884768621662192954770 \\
 2 & \color{red}{7.853593279971248}19988350123943 & 
                 7.85359327997124820007989934704 \\
 3 & \color{red}{10.995591063064381582985917}5120 & 
                 10.9955910630643815829859174825 \\
 4 & \color{red}{14.1371662162062924251354912335} & 
                 14.1371662162062924251354912335 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Doing the same with the $[3,3]$ and $[4,4]$ Padé approximants, we face a cubic and a quartic polynomial in $t$ giving respectively (with nasty radicals) for the first root  $\color{red}{1.292695}978$ and $\color{red}{1.2926957}201$.

Comment: This is great. Can we show that the zero must be close to $(2n+1)\pi/2$ ?

Comment: @Medo You are looking for $x>0$ such that $\cos(x)=e^{-x}$. Now $e^{-x} \approx 0$ if $x\gg 0$, so the roots must be closer and closer to the roots of $\cos(x)=0$, i.e., $(2n+1)\pi/2$.

Comment: Did  you write all these numbers? Omg.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely possible. It is solved for general case $\cos{tx}$ [here](https://alints.ru/integrator/Rounds/BerkleyBeeRounds/BerkleyBeeRounds.html) using Laplace transform in section "2021". Basically, I found hundreds of such integrals in that web [alints.com](https://alints.com/).